# Adding Dropdownlist to gridview column from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to add dropdownlist to a column in my gridview. I have something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();

        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Selection", typeof(string));

        }

 DropDownList ddlSelection= new DropDownList();

        ddlSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("one"));
        ddlSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("two"));


DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow(); 
NewRow[0] = lblname.Text;
NewRow[1] = ddlSelection.Items;
dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
```

I'm getting a typeof error. Anyone who can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: dt.Columns.Add("Selection", typeof(string)); i think this is the problem. The gridview doesnt show te dropdownlist, its shows the string of the control name like:System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection. Supposed to show the control.

Comment: You can not add dropdownlist that way if you are doing that, You need to create a template field and add it to gridview dynamically.Why not add dropdown in aspx page ?

Comment: I tought maybe its possible to do it in the codebehind. But youre right. I can do it in the front end

Comment: It is possible to this in code behind, But see you are adding a control to a DataRow , So now think what you do to add a control in GridView ?You create a Template field right? So You can create a template field and add it dynamically, But if there is no complication or need i think the better or sane way will be to do it in aspx page . I posted an example i did once. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add a control to a DataTable, try handling the DataBound action of the gridview and iterate with a foreach(GridviewRow r in GridView1.rows) loop adding a control to whichever cell of the gridview.

```
 //edit:    
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();

        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Selection", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));
        }

        DropDownList ddlSelection = new DropDownList();

        ddlSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("one"));
        ddlSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("two"));

        for(int i= 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
            NewRow[1] = "dropdownlist"+i;
            dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow r in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            DropDownList ddlSelection = new DropDownList();

            ddlSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("one"));
            ddlSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("two"));
            r.Cells[0].Controls.Add(ddlSelection);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This one works, but the new column with the dropdownlist is showing up in the left of the gridview, before "  dt.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));". Any idea how to make it disappear in the right, after my first column with the names?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, are you saying you want the dropdown to appear on the left? so just change r.Cells[index to where you want it to appear] look at edit.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do that will be ,Create a user control of what you required and load it as Template field.
But this template field will clear every time page loads so you need it to create everytime page loads.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
          {
                int index = dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr);
                 if(index =1)
            {
                TemplateField tF = new TemplateField();
                tF.HeaderText = dr["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();
                tF.ItemTemplate = LoadTemplate("/xxxxxx.ascx");
                GridView1.Columns.Add(tF);
            }
         }
```